# One who neglects the rendering of help

Tags: nouns

How will I write this statement in a shortest yet understandable way? And is there a one word noun for this? 
"One who often abstains from, or neglects, the rendering of aid, or assistance"

Answer (score 0):

They could be said to be [stubbornly](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stubbornly) [self-sufficient](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-sufficient).

> **stubborn** - fixed or set in purpose or opinion; resolute
>
> **self-sufficient** - having extreme confidence in one's own resources, powers, etc.